# What stats should you include on poisson regression plot

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization

[image]

I have this quasi poisson regression plot and I will be presenting in at a conference (obviously it will look better than this). What statistics should you be presenting? I know likely the p value and coefficient but is there anything else that should be added?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the data? It's hard to understand what's going on with just "Number" and "Months" on the axes.

Comment: Its just number is basically a count from a survey and months is number of months on a medication.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd change the axes to say "Months on Medication" and "Number of Patients." I'd report the number of zeros, and be able to verbally address the issue of [zero-inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model#Zero-inflated_Poisson). Definitely report the estimated overdispersion parameter, because one certainly expects overdispersion when medication use month-to-month is clearly correlated. And report the usual regression coefficients and statistics of interest. Other commenters might be able to suggest more or tweak my suggestions.

Comment: Just to make sure, what are the usual statistics of interest you are referring to?

Comment: "Number of Patients" is still vague - number of patients who did what? responded to medication?

Comment: @Ryan: You could add an arrow next to your blue curve and label it "Expected Number of Patients (who did what?)"

Comment: I think reporting the usual regression coefficients might be tricky, unless you make it clear they refer to impact of "Months on Medication" on the log-transformed expected number of patients.

Comment: You could add a pointwise confidence band around your blue curve too.